# font-face works on all but one page- what could be the issue?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Font-Face is working on all but one of my pages- [About](http://www.massagebybodyworx.com/about). Because it's just the one page that isn't working, I don't think it could be an issue with file paths. Also, everything worked great locally. What could be the cause? How do I remedy?

Thank you.

```
<div id="about">
    <div class="blurb">
        <p style="text-decoration:underline;color:#f20000;"><span style="color:#282828;">Welcome to BodywoRx</span></p>
</div><!-- end blurb -->

    <div class="banner-image">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/large.jpg" alt="about-place-holder" id="aph" />
    </div><!-- end banner-image -->
    <p>Body WoRx was founded on the belief that many dysfunctions of the body can be healed through massage therapy.  In a world where prescriptions are written for variety of symptoms, we offer an alternative solution to helping the body heal itself.  We are located in historic downtown Grand Prairie, conveniently centered between Fort Worth and Dallas.</p>
    <div class="bio">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/bridgett.jpg" alt="bridgett-freiburger" id="bf" />
        <p>Bridgett suffered from chronic neck, back, and shoulder pain for many years.  She went to many doctors, specialists, had many MRI&apos;s, but no one knew what was causing the pain.  She had been prescribed countless medications to help ease discomfort, but nothing to address the cause.  Bridgett stumbled across massage therapy and has since become a firm believer and advocate in its many benefits and healing properties.  Before getting into massage therapy, Bridgett served in the Marine Corps, and then continued supporting the war fighter while working at Bell Helicopter. Bridgett is a graduate of North Texas School of Swedish Massage.</p>
    </div><!-- end bio -->
</div><!-- end about -->

#about .banner-image {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#about span {
    font-family: alexandria-bold;
    font-size: 193%;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#about p {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#about .bio {
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#about .bio p {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 35px;
    width: 655px;
}
```

Comment: @arttronics i deleted the link to the home page, yes, but corrected the link to the About page in the question seeing as it was especially relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have **3 out of 6** `@font-face` fonts that are at the specified location for **main** and **about** page.

**Firefox w/Firebug Net Tab Screenshot:**
[image]

**Side note:** Your missing **closing** `anchor tag` in `id="address"` in both (maybe more) those pages.

---

**Status Update:** I have found the solution for your `@font-face` issue with **Firefox**. There are 2 issues.

First, let's **take a trip back in time** when you originally published your LIVE webpage link explaining you have no issues with it.  *All links below are useable and reflect the format seen.*

It's understood `works` is a **TYPO** and should be `worx`. *This obviously is not your website.*

[`http://massagebybodyworks.com/`](http://massagebybodyworks.com/)

OK so, here's the corrected version... ***right***?

[`http://massagebybodyworx.com/`](http://massagebybodyworx.com/)

Well, the corrected version **worxs** as required (pun intended).

Now let's look at the link for the **About Page** that's **not** working:

[`http://www.massagebybodyworx.com/about`](http://www.massagebybodyworx.com/about)

Put on the breaks! *Do you see the error?* Well, as it turns out your **About Page** is using **`www`** for the anchor tag and it **should not**. That's why it breaks. The anchor tag should be:

[`http://massagebybodyworx.com/about`](http://massagebybodyworx.com/about)

Having said that, here's your corrected homepage with the **`www`** used and notice it breaks in Firefox too:
[`http://www.massagebybodyworx.com/`](http://www.massagebybodyworx.com/)

OK, issue 1 is resolved. Just fix your anchor tag **not** to use **`www`** in the link.

Issue 2 is regarding your servers `.htaccess` file since that controls how incoming handling of links are dealt with.

Specifically, whenever somebody manually types or visits your webpage via **`www`** prefix, your server ***needs to be configured*** to serve them the non **`www`** site. Then, your webpage is presented as you intended. Research more about [**`.htaccess file`**](http://davidwalsh.name/no-www-using-htaccess-file) on Google if you need to.

---

***So then, why does it fail in Firefox and not Chrome?***

Firefox has different security rules in place and using `@font-face` incorrectly will cause it to break because of [**Same Origin Policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) rules.

The reason it breaks in Firefox can be seen in your HTML webpage markup. There, you are calling up your CSS file responsible for the `@font-face` fonts using an [**absolute URL**](http://kb.iu.edu/data/abwp.html):

`"http://massagebybodyworx.com/wp-content/themes/bodyworx/style.css"`

Then, accessing your site via **`www`** will cause Same Origin Policy rule to be applied resulting in your `@font-face` fonts not to show as intended.

You can however use a [**relative URL**](http://kb.iu.edu/data/abwp.html) to make Firefox happy:

`"wp-content/themes/bodyworx/style.css"`

Having a **relative URL** also means there aren't issues with `@font-face` for when your site is visited with or without the **`www`** in the incoming link, but proper handling of the `.htaccess` file is preferred.

**Side note:** You have a white space issue that should be URL encoded for a link tag in your head section. Here's how it should look:

```
<link rel="pingback" href="BodywoRx%20Massage" />
```

Comment: it seems that this problem is common with FF. any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: also, why is it only happening on this particular page?

Comment: My current answer is irrelevant to the browser used. Those 3 fonts are simply missing in that directory for both pages. As to why the other 3 loaded fonts work in Chrome but not in Firefox could mean that Firefox can't use those fonts. That said, try using a different font-face font to test if it renders in Firefox.

Comment: OK so, **now** I see it works on the other pages (odd as it was not seen before!?). For your `about` page, temporary remove `id="about"` to see if this corrects the problem with the `@font-face` issue.

Comment: Removing `id="about"` didn't have an effect, nor did replacing alexandria with a different font.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have provided a working solution in my Answer in the Status Update section. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you a million times for your patience and problem solving skills. I've corrected the problem and all is well!

Answer (score 0):

This page is picking up the styles for the #about div as below

```
#about span {
    font-family: alexandria-bold;
    font-size: 193%;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }
```

I'm assuming you want it to be the smaller text like on the other pages? If so either remove it from the #about div or put the following into your css to make it the same as corresponding pages

```
#about .blurb p,
#about .blurb p span {
    font-family: alexandria;
    font-size: 193%;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-decoration: underline #f20000;
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your help. however, it's not just the `<p>` and `<span>` that isn't pulling font-face, it's the entire page.. links in the header(header.php) and info in the footer(footer.php) included. everything should be styled just as it is on all other pages- nav links, text, and footer info.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that browser can't load a webfont on the about page from the following directory: http://massagebybodyworx.com/wp-content/themes/bodyworx/type/

I think this is related to server configuration which allows access to that directory's content from massagebybodyworx.com but not from www.massagebybodyworx.com, treating that as an attempt of cross-site scripting.